# What are standard basis vectors coordinates of? Themselves?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

A basis is a set of linearly independent vectors that span a vector space $V$. A coordinate vector $v$ can be used to reference vectors within this space. The components of *v* are the coefficients of a linear combination of the basis vectors.
Sticking with subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$ (for simplicity), any basis vector we choose can be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors comprising the standard basis.

For example, consider a basis $\left\{  a,b\right\}$ where: $$a=\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} \, \,\,\,b=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2  \end{bmatrix}$$  The vectors of this basis can be rewritten as: $$a = 2i + 0j   \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,b = 0i + 2j$$ $a$ and $b$ are just coordinate vectors. So what are *i* and *j* coordinates of? Themselves? The vector $a$ in our basis could be rewritten as the following:

$$a = 2i + 0j = 2\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} + 0 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1  \end{bmatrix} = 2 * 1 * i + 0 * 0 * j + 0 * 0 * i + 0 * 1 * j = \,\,... $$

This interpretation of the standard basis vectors seems circular and recurses infinitely. Is there a better way to think about these entities?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: $\{(1,1),(2,2)\}$ is not a basis since the vectors are not linearly independent.

Comment: I think this question is poorly written and should use mathjax but asks about (what I think is) a legitimate confusion and need not be closed or downvoted.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the incorrect example basis. I updated the question to use a linearly independent set of vectors as the example basis.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you for linking the tutorial. I updated the post to use this notation. Hopefully, it is a little more clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there's a lot of things being mixed around in this question. First things first $\{(1,1),(2,2)\}$ is **not** a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$; it is not linearly independent because $(2,2) = 2(1,1)$.

To put ourselves on firm footing,

> **Definition:** Given some vector space $V$ with basis $\beta$ and $v \in V$ the **coordinate vector** for $v$ is $[v]_\beta = (a_1,\dots,a_n)$ where $a_i$ are the scalars needed to write $v$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors.

You write that in $\mathbb{R}^2$, any basis vector can be expressed as a linear combination of the standard basis vectors. This is technically correct, but I believe the source of your confusion. As you seem to understand, there are many different possible choices of basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. The **standard basis** is $\{i,j\}$ where $i = (1,0),j=(0,1)$. Another possible example of a basis is $\{(1,0),(-2,1)\}$, and yes
\begin{align*}
(-1,0) & = -1i \\
(-2,1) & = -2i+j
\end{align*}
so that these vectors are a linear combination of the standard basis vectors.

**But,** it's the *doubling up* of the term *basis vector* that is unclear. Once you pick a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ you stick to it, and no longer would you refer to another set of vectors as *the* basis vectors. This part introduces the circular definition you are referring to.

With the definition of a coordinate vector and terminology I stated, let's revisit your example.

> For example, consider a basis {a, b} where a = (2, 0) and b = (0, 2). The vectors of this basis can be rewritten as *a = 2i + 0j* and *b = 0i + 2j*. *a* and *b* are just coordinate vectors.

**Issues:**

- As I mentioned before this isn't a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.
- "The vectors of this basis can be written as $a = 2i+0j$ and $b = 0i+2j$" is awkward. You would simply say instead "The *vectors* $a,b$ may be written as $a = 2i+0j$ and $b=0i+2j$.
- You write immediately after "$a,b$ are just coordinate vectors." To talk about coordinate vectors, **you must first fix a basis**. Once you've picked a basis, it makes no sense to ask what the basis vectors are coordinates of if you've understood the definition of a coordinate vector.

To bring it all together, here's an example that brings together all the points.

**Example:** Let $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and lets fix the basis $\beta = \{(1,0),(-2,1)\}$. Consider the vector $(3,2) \in V$.

- We may write $v$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors as
  $$
  (3,2) = 7(1,0)+2(-2,1).
  $$
- The **coordinate vector** $[v]_\beta = (7,2)$ because these are the coefficients in the linear combination representing $v$.

If instead we took $\beta = \{i,j\}$ then for the same vector $(3,2)$ we have
$$
(3,2) = 3(1,0) +2(0,1) =3i+2j
$$
and the coordinate vector for $v$ is trivially itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a basis of $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, each vector in $V$ can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors.

When you use the *standard basis* $i = (1,0)$, $j=(0,1)$ each vector $(a,b)$ is its own "coordinate vector" since
$$
(x,y) = xi + yj.
$$

If you think of another basis, say $v = (1,2), w = (1,3)$, then you can express any vector as a linear combination of $v$ and $w$. So for example
$$
2v -3w = (-1, -5)
$$
so the coordinate vector of $(-1, -5)$ with respect to the basis $\{v,w\}$ is $(2, -3)$

Note:
In basis $\{v,w\}$ the coordinate vector of $v$ is $(1,0)$ because
$$
v = 1v + 0w.
$$
but you should *not* think of that as the same object as the standard basis vector $i$.

That is why I think the phrase "coordinate vector" is ill chosen, and may be part
of what is confusing you. But if that's what your book and course
use, learn it.